# Create a view class that is a combination of two views Android

Tags: java, android, image, download

In my app, I have a screen that displays some images next to text. These images are downloaded from the internet, so there will be some latency in displaying them. Right now I have an ImageView and a ProgressBar overlaying each other, and toggling the visibilities when the Bitmap becomes available. Is there any way to combine the two into one class that will handle it all in case I want to use this somewhere else?

Comment: Just to make it clear, do you want to draw the imageView with the progressview, as one nice view? One way would be to extend progressBar and draw the image in the ondraw(Canvasn canvas) using a Rect. Another way to make it resuable is take the imageview and progressbar to a different xml file and use merge tags when you want to include them in aother layout file.

Comment: Extending ProgressBar worked perfectly! I initially extended ImageView, but with no avail, this however solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: glad it worked, I'm going to write an answer, would you please accept it, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about solving the problem is to make your own custom view which extends [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) and draw the image in the ondraw(Canvasn canvas) using a [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html). That way, your image can be embedded in your view and you can always make it reusable by allowing your self to set the image via a setter/resource xml files which specify the attributes that go along with your custom view. Here's a reusable ProgressButton that I wrote that maybe of use to you, it shows how I did something similar to what I described (it's one which I think works well):

[PregressButton](https://github.com/SundeepK/ProgressButton)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a number of ways to combine widgets into a single custom class. Have a read of [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). This should help you decide which approach you want to use for your situation.